# Word for allowing/sanctioning someone’s feelings

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m thinking of a word that I would use to describe a situation in which one person (she) is listening to another talk about his problems and instead of shutting him down by saying his feelings are invalid, she just listens and says something like, “Yeah, that must be terrible for you.” (This is a good thing not a bad thing). I was thinking of something along the lines of

> She **_______ (validated/allowed/sanctioned?)** his feelings

I just want to say that she did not deny what he was feeling and didn’t try to tell him not to feel it

Comment: 'enabling' is a word you might be after but I cannot use it as an answer if your title is 'allowing/sanctioning' . It is used more broadly than conversational support when support may not be the best course. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enabling

Comment: Wouldn't most people say '... sympathised with how he felt'?

Answer (score 1):

[**acknowledge**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/acknowledge) (American Heritage):

> a. To express recognition of; make notice of: "When he saw me acknowledge him, he smiled as if we were dear friends" (Angela Patrinos).

**validate**

I'm not finding a dictionary definition that matches with its current use in this context.  This verb is a bit more active than *acknowledge*.  When someone validates your feelings, you don't just get heard, you also get reassurance that your feelings are reasonable and understandable.  (With *acknowledge*, all that happens is that someone took in what you said and confirmed that they heard what you said.

An even more basic option would be:

**be heard**

This means that someone heard you.

Answer (score 0):

**give ear to**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+ear+to)

> give one's ear to someone or something

As in:

> I gave an ear to Mary so she could tell me her problems.

Answer (score 0):

***affirm*** - Offer (someone) emotional support or encouragement. 
([*en.oxforddictionaries.com*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/affirm))

The "emotional support" aspect gets mixed up in legal meanings when talking about the word *affirm*.  But this sort of bolstering is *affirmation*.